# Getting error on Location Manager Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am trying to use this code that I got from

https://github.com/Intermark/Buoy/tree/master/Buoy/Swift

I am getting the following error in BUOYListener.swift and `enter code here`BUOYBeacon.swift

Any idea as how to fix this?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Swift 2.0, the Swift compiler requires the method signature to strictly match that of the protocol you're implementing. In this case, that's CLLocationManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralManagerDelegate.

The correct Swift signature for *didRangeBeacons* is:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)
```

For *peripheralManagerDidUpdateState*:

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
```

Finally, *startAdvertising* requires a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary, but you're casting your *peripheralData* to `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. Use the following cast instead:

```
self.beaconRegion.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(nil) as! [String: AnyObject]
```